# Why would I want to hit myself with a Face Flask?

Tags: dead-cells

After examining a Buddha Statue I found a Face Flask. The description makes it sound very unhelpful.

> Crush a flask on your forehead dealing low damage to yourself.

What is the purpose of a Face Flask? Why would I want to deal damage to myself?

[image]

Comment: I don't have proof of this, but this might be a reference to the game Blasphemous, whose protagonist heals himself by smashing vials of blood into his face. This would also explain the connection to a specific kind of sword @user1337 mentioned in their answer.

Comment: @waldrumpus You're right about the Blasphemous connection. Looks like the flask is [an official crossover item](https://www.destructoid.com/dead-cells-everyone-is-here-update-guest-characters-hollow-knight-blasphemous-hyper-light-drifter/).

Answer (score 14):

The one in the screenshot is particularly bad as it can only be used to trigger "after taking damage" effects, but the face flask can also have attributes, like increase speed for x time, create toxic cloud around you, etc...

I've never actually found one that I thought was worth using; but I guess it can be, depending on the strategy.

Note that, although it does damage to yourself, it does not reset your kill spree.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to synergize with the Spite Sword as it deals crits for 8 seconds after taking damage.